# Use of Material Icons following the documentation

Tags: html, angular, icons, material-design

I'm trying to implement and use material icons inside my angular 4 project, but i'm encountering a strange issue.

I have 2 different html files related to 2 differents modules:

- interventi.component.html
- sync.component.html

[image]

I've created a Material Module that imports and exports all the mat-components(modules) that i need, including the MatIconModule.

- interventi.module.ts imports Material module.
- sync.module.ts imports Material module.

**Now listen to this :**

1) In interventi.component.html i'm showing a material-icon with

```
 <mat-icon aria-hidden="true" class="material-icons md-18" matSuffix (click)="customerModel = null">delete</mat-icon>
```

2) Inside sync.component.html **I CAN'T DO THE SAME** . Intellij recognize the  tag but i will not see the icon, i will see "delete" as text, even if i try to copy all the code row shown above.

As the documentation of google says, I've put this link

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

inside my **index.html.**

***Where i'm doing wrong?***

I'm near to give in to common-use of material icons, putting the import link inside all the html.files that use material-icons.

I'm confused also by these twice methods to implement material icons...

For information completion, here's the Material Module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {CdkTableModule} from "@angular/cdk/table";


import {
        [...others..],
        MatIconModule,
        [...others..]
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        [...others..],
        MatIconModule,
        [...others..]
    ],
    exports: [
        [...others..],
        MatIconModule,
        [...others..]
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Comment: Thats strange!  your code and approach seems to be correct

Comment: Doh! (cit. Homer Simpson)

Comment: Do you use other imported font in the second (sync ) component?